# How to check if array is inside of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some kind of specific problem. I have multidimensional array which looks like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(9997)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(327)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(11) "Web Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "1" 
    }
    [1]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(9998)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(327)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(7) "Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
     }
    [2]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(9999)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(327)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(7) "Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(10000)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(327)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(7) "Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(10001)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(327)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(7) "Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(10002)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(327)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(11) "Web Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(8828)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(298)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(11) "Web Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(8829)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(298)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(7) "Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(8830)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(298)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(7) "Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(8831)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(298)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(7) "Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(8832)
      ["project_id"]=>
      int(298)
      ["projectType_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameter"]=>
      string(11) "Web Server?"
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["severity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is to knew about differences between those tables. I mean how many rows are present in table 1 and are absent in table 2. How many rows are absent in table 1 and present in table 2 and how many rows are equals in both tables.

I tried with creating loops over array checking each row and comparing it. My code is posted bellow. It got me nowhere..

```
foreach ($bigArray[0] as $new){
    foreach($bigArray[1] as $old){
        if ($new== $old)
            echo "it is the same";
        else
            echo "it is different";
    }
}
```

All I got is `it is different` all time...

Is there any function to count this kind of stuff? (first column -ID is unique for each row so it should not have been taken into consideration.

Comment: A good starting point would be by start looking at array_diff: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: How you want two rows to be compared? by 'id' prop or by full content?

Comment: everything but the id(which is different for every row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [array_udiff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) in conjunction with [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php). Somehow like this:

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    if (isset($a['id'])) unset($a['id']);
    if (isset($b['id'])) unset($b['id']);
    return count(array_diff_assoc($a, $b))? 0 : 1;
}

$result = array_udiff($bigArray[0], $bigArray[1], 'compare');
if (!count($result)) echo 'it is the same';
```